# jQuery remove last child without specifying tag type

Tags: jquery

I will probably only have to deal with `div` tags, so this code should always work:

```
$('#top-info div:last-child').remove();
```

It does work. But I'm wondering how I could do it without specifying the child type.

I tried this:

```
$('#top-info *:last-child').remove();
```

I figured if would remove the the last child, whatever its type. But instead, it seemed to work recursively. It removed the 2nd `<div>`, but it also removed the `<p>` contained in the 1st `<div>`.

I confirmed this by adding a 2nd `<p>` to the first `<div>` and `remove()` took out the entire 2nd `<div>`, and the 2nd (last) `<p>` in the 1st `<div>`.

Is that expected behavior?
How would I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("#top-info").children().last().remove();
```

Comment: This works for selecting. You just have to add `.remove()` to remove the element. Thanks!

Comment: True, I added the remove().

Comment: Thanks. I would have given you the checkmark anyway, but it forced me to wait. Wow, you are gaining points fast today!